# Why is my GitHub Pages website not displaying?

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I'm completely new to creating and hosting websites, but I am trying to publish my website code to github and view it with github pages.

I've created a new repository and added in my project file which contains an HTML file, a CSS file, and an images folder with one .jpg image inside.

My github pages site is set to be built from the master branch, however when I try to look at my website, only the repository title and my added comment show up. When I try to view my website locally, everything works correctly.

https://aharri71.github.io/Hogwarts/

My github: https://github.com/aharri71/Hogwarts

Comment: Well... it does work perfectly well...

Answer (score 1):

Could you add this folder here https://github.com/aharri71/Hogwarts/tree/master/Hogwarts/Admission as your root folder and rename the Admission.html to index.html and then force push to GitHub.

Why do you need to do the above mentioned?
- well, GitHub checks for an "index.html" file in the root folder of the branch you set in the settings for GitHub pages and renders it.